# Materialize showStaggeredList

Tags: materialize

In Materialize **ScrollFire** one of the options is **showStaggeredList**. It slides every list item form **left to right**. Can it possible to slide them from **right to left**?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<h3>Scroll down</h3>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<ul id="staggered-test">
          <li>
            <h4><a href="#">List Item</a></h4>
            <p>This is a description</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h4><a href="#">List Item</a></h4>
            <p>This is a description</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h4><a href="#">List Item</a></h4>
            <p>This is a description</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h4><a href="#">List Item</a></h4>
            <p>This is a description</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h4><a href="#">List Item</a></h4>
            <p>This is a description</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

javascript call fuction

```
 var options = [

      {selector: '#staggered-test', offset: 400, callback: function(el) {
        Materialize.showStaggeredList($(el));
      } }

    ];
    Materialize.scrollFire(options);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2qg18zzb/

The **jsfiddle** example is left to right, **I need it form right to left**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution...

I have to edit **materialize.js**. I am using beta release **v0.98.0**.

In mine **materialize.js** line **4757** change **translateX: "-100px"** to **translateX: "100px"**

so mainly edit **showStaggeredList** function:

```
 Materialize.showStaggeredList = function(selectorOrEl) {
    var element;
    if (typeof(selectorOrEl) === 'string') {
      element = $(selectorOrEl);
    } else if (typeof(selectorOrEl) === 'object') {
      element = selectorOrEl;
    } else {
      return;
    }
    var time = 0;
    element.find('li').velocity(
        { translateX: "100px"},
        { duration: 0 });

    element.find('li').each(function() {
      $(this).velocity(
        { opacity: "1", translateX: "0"},
        { duration: 800, delay: time, easing: [60, 10] });
      time += 120;
    });
  };
```